# Combine list of tibble tables if they have the same columns

Tags: r, rbind

I have data of the form

```
[[1]] 
   a b c
1  3 4 8 
[[2]] 
   d e f
1  6 7 9 
[[3]] 
   g h i
1  1 4 5 
[[4]] 
   a b c
1  9 5 2 
[[5]] 
   d e f
1  5 8 0
```

I want to combine this to

```
[[1]]
  a b c
1 3 4 8
2 9 5 2
[[1]]
  d e f
1 6 7 9
2 5 8 0
[[3]]
  g h i
1 1 4 5
```

That is, I want to rbind the tibble tables in a list if they have the same column names. Could someone help me out? Kind regards.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: Isn't this a reproducible example?

Comment: `list(c(a = 3, b = 4, c = 8), c(d = 6, e = 7, f = 9), c(g = 1, 
h = 4, i = 5), c(a = 9, b = 5, c = 2), c(d = 5, e = 8, f = 0))` is reproducible example in your case. Try using `dput(data)`.

Comment: No. We need to able to copy/paste in our sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
lapply(split(lst, sapply(lst, function(x) toString(names(x)))), function(y) do.call(rbind, y))

$`a, b, c`
     a b c
[1,] 3 4 8
[2,] 9 5 2

$`d, e, f`
     d e f
[1,] 6 7 9
[2,] 5 8 0

$`g, h, i`
     g h i
[1,] 1 4 5
```

Or a more succinct option (proposed by @Ronak Shah):

```
tapply(lst, sapply(lst, function(x) toString(names(x))), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

Comment: `split` + `lapply` can be replaced with `tapply` which will make it a little shorter. `tapply(lst, sapply(lst, function(x) toString(names(x))), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))`

Comment: @Ronak Shah that's very clever, thanks fot this tip!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty messy but it may works

```
x <- unique(lapply(dummy, function(x) names(x)))
y <- lapply(dummy, function(x) names(x))
z <- match(y, x)
res <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
for (i in 1:length(z)) {
  res[[z[i]]] <- rbind(res[[z[i]]], dummy[[i]])
  
}

[[1]]
     a b c
[1,] 3 4 8
[2,] 9 5 2

[[2]]
     d e f
[1,] 6 7 9
[2,] 5 8 0

[[3]]
     g h i
[1,] 1 4 5
```